# I lost my PS4 game disc, can I continue to play if I buy the digital version?

Tags: ps4, physical-media, ghost-of-tsushima

I lost my PS4 game disc of Ghost of Tsushima, and I want to buy a digital version from PSN, which is now on discounted price.
Will I be able to continue my own game or do I have to start over everything?

Answer (score 1):

Typically digital/physical saves are the same, as long as it's the same game version and region.

As discussed [here](https://www.resetera.com/threads/do-ps4-saves-work-between-physical-and-digital-versions.65712/) and [here](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/691087-playstation-4/79415834).